# Oracle Fusion HCM cannot get data from Rest api /workers

Tags: oracle-fusion-apps

Do we need any special permmission to call the Rest api /workers .
As my understanding, we can get login user's info from api /workers with PersonNumber param. When I call api, get no item.
See below image.

/[image]